# Does Megillat Esther need to be read without interruption?

Tags: purim, megillat-esther

Suppose one wishes to read *megillah* but finds it physically difficult to do so without interruption.  Is it permissible to read part of it, take a break, and then continue later?  Or must the mitzvah be fulfilled without interruption?

Answer (score 3):

See https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Megillah.2?lang=bi

> קְרָאָהּ סֵרוּגִין, וּמִתְנַמְנֵם, יָצָא.
>
> If one read the Megilla at intervals, pausing and resuming, or while
> he is dozing off, he has fulfilled his obligation.

Also https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A6

*Seif* 5

> קראה סירוגין, דהיינו שפסק בה ושהה, ואחר כך חזר למקום שפסק, אפילו שהה
> כדי לגמור את כולה, יצא.
>
> הגה: ואפילו סח בינתיים. מיהו גוערין במי שסח בינתיים, כדלקמן סימן תרצ"ב
> סעיף ב'. (הרשב"א סי' רמ"ד).

Approximate translation:

If one read and then interrupted, even if he interrupted so long that he would have been able to finish the entire megillah in the interruption, he is *yotze*.

**Rema**: However one should not talk in the breaks.

Answer (score 1):

The Kaf Hachaim 690:32 notes that one should not make a break during the reading of the Megillah since it is a letter . A letter is normally read without interruption.  Therefore, it is not lechatchila to pause between the reading . However as noted in the other answer one is yotzei the mitzvah even with an interruption.

Text of the Kaf Hachaim:

לב) שם. קראה סירוגין וכו׳ אין להפסיק בקריאת המגילה מפני שנקראת אגרת ודרך אגרת לקרותו בלא הפסקה לכך צריך לכתחלה לקרותה בלא הפסק כדרך שקורין אגרת. לבוש:

Answer (score 0):

As the answers above have stated, there can be pauses.

There is an idea, a Minhag brought down by Sages, (similar to the Kaf Hachaim) that the Migilah should be read (at Home) without stops between Passages as it says **ככתבם - as it was written**. (9;27)

And being that separation of Passukim as we know them were something that Ezra did, who was of course after the writing of the Migilah.

**Ibn Ezra (9;27)**

**ככתבם** – הטעם שתקרא המגלה. ובעבור שעזרא הסופר הפסיק הפסוקים והוא היה אחרי שנים רבות, צוו חכמינו ז״ל שלא יפסוק הקורא בסוף הפסוק.

**שבלי הלקט השלם (Hebrewbooks, pg 199.):**

ואמר לי רבינו יהודה בן רבינו יצחק זצ"ל כך היה מנהגו של אביו לאחר שהיה יוצא מבית הכנסת היה קורא את המגילה בספר ולא היה מסיים בסיום הפסוק אלא מתחיל אחר וממתין וראיה לדבר חמש מאות איש ואת ויזתא עשרת בני המן

והרב אברהם בן עזרא ז"ל כתב בפירוש אסתר בעבור שעזרא הספר הפסיק הפסוקים ולא היה אמר אחר שנים רבות צוו חכמים זצ"ל שלא יפסיק הקורא בסוף פסוק וכך אנו נוהגין ברומה

And so tells me Rabbeinu Yehudah ben Rabbeinu Yitzchak, (one of the Authors of Tosafos) so was the Minhag of his father, after leaving the Shul he would read the Migilah with a sefer, and he would not end at each Passuk, rather he would start and and end wherever.

A proof to this is the Ten Names of Haman are said with the previous Passuk in one breath (Migilah 16b). (If we are reading a regular Torah portion we need to stop by the end of each Passuk, as indicated by עזרא, proving that the Gemarah wanted at least one Passuk read without a stop)

And the Ibn Ezra wrote in his Perush on Esther (9;27) since Ezra separated Passukim, and you have to say the Rabbi's instituted reading it like that, only after many years, and so are נוהג in Rome.